# DART/FLUTTER - Checkbox is checked in a ListBuilder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

You will see I am generating a series of checkboxes dynamically within a ListBuilder and I need to identify which of them is marked as true, the problem is that I can't think of how to do it.

Here you have the list code which is dynamically generated through a list of strings:

```
      return SlideTile(
    title: "Incidencia del solicitante",
    listBuilder: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
        child: MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).removePadding(
              removeTop: true,),
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    10, 0, 10, 5),
                primary: false,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: blocAssistant.incidencias_solicitante.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return checkBox(text: blocAssistant.incidencias_solicitante[index]);
                }
            )
        )
    ),
    desc: "Aqui debe indicar el tipo de error de la incidencia.",
  );
```

And here you have the code of the checkboxes of which I need to recognize their status individually.

```
class checkBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const checkBox({
    required this.text,
  });
  final String text;

  @override
  State<checkBox> createState() => _CheckBoxState();
}

class _CheckBoxState extends State<checkBox> {
  bool checkboxListTileValue = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: checkboxListTileValue,
      onChanged: (newValue) {

          setState(() => checkboxListTileValue = newValue!);
      },
      title: Text(
        widget.text,
        style: MainTheme.title2.override(
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
      tileColor: MainTheme.tertiaryColor,
      activeColor: MainTheme.primaryColor,
      checkColor: MainTheme.tertiaryColor,
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the class keep the bool value to false.

```
bool ischanged = false;


checkbox(

value: ischanged,

onchanged(value) {

setstate ((){

ischanged = value!;

}
)
```

This way you can recognize their status individually.

Comment: Please use code blocks(triple ticks) to properly format your code

Comment: Yeah got it done!

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to add 10 checkboxes

then add 10 bool values such as


bool ischanged = false;

bool ischanged1 = false;

bool ischanged2 = false;

bool ischanged4 = false;

bool ischanged5 = false;

bool ischanged6 = false;

bool ischanged7 = false;

bool ischanged8 = false;

bool ischanged9 = false;
```